# using url parameters in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating an `angularjs` application, and I have my `app.js` as following :

```
var capValueRecruitApp = angular.module('capValueRecruitApp', ['ui.router']);

capValueRecruitApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
      controller: 'offresController'
    })
    .state('offres', {
      url: '/offres',
      templateUrl: 'views/offres.html',
      controller: 'offresController'
    })
    .state('offres.detail', {
      url: '/offres/:id',
      templateUrl: 'views/offres.detail.html',
      controller: 'offresController'
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```

when I enter to `#/offres` I get a list of offers in the `offres.html` page, and I want when I enter to `#/offres/5` to get the entry with the key 5 in the `offres.detail.html`.

in the ui route documentation I solved that with using /offres/:id and in the controller I test the existence of the parameter I passed to the url as following:

```
capValueRecruitApp.controller('offresController', function($scope, offresFactory, $stateParams) {
  console.log($stateParam.id);
  offresFactory.getList().then(function(list) {
    $scope.offres = list.data;
    console.log($scope.offres);
  }, function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  });

});
```

but when I enter to `#/offres/5` the application routes me to the default route with is `/home`.

How can I solve that ?

## Edit :

After changes I made as following :

```
.state('offres.detail', {
      url: '/:id',
      templateUrl: 'views/offres.detail.html',
      controller: 'offresController',
      resolve: {
        offresDetail: ['offresFactory', '$stateProvider', function(offresFactory, $stateProvider) {
          return offresFactory.getOffresDetail($stateProvider.id);
        }]
      }
    })
```

and in controller :

```
capValueRecruitApp.controller('offresController', function($scope, offresFactory, offresDetail) {
  offresFactory.getList().then(function(list) {
    console.log(offresDetail.data);
    $scope.offres = list.data;
    console.log($scope.offres);
  }, function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  });


});
```

and my factory :

```
capValueRecruitApp.factory('offresFactory', function($http) {
    var factory = {
        getList: function() {
            return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/offres')
                .then(function(response) {

            return response;

                }, function(error) {
                    return 'There was an error getting data';
                });
        },
    getOffresDetail: function(id) {
      return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/offres/'+id)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(id);
          return response;

        }, function(error) {
          return 'There was an error getting data';
        });
    }
    };
    return factory;
});
```

as you can see I have two console.log one in the factory to test the `id` and the other to test the `offresDetail.data` but I cant see any message in the console and the view didn't injected and neither I can see some error message.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a child state, a url to it is relative to the parent state. So in your case you defined this state: "/offres/offres/5". So just change the child state's url to be relative to the parent state, like this:

```
.state('offres.detail', {
    url: '/:id',  // <-- change to this
    templateUrl: 'views/offres.detail.html',
    controller: 'offresController'
});
```

I would also suggest that you **resolve** the necessary data for your state controller. Example:

```
.state('offres.detail', {
    url: '/:id',
    templateUrl: 'views/offres.detail.html',
    controller: 'offresController',
    resolve: {
        offresDetail: ['offresFactory', '$stateProvider', function(offresFactory, $stateProvider) {
            return offresFactory.getOffresDetail($stateProvider.id);
        }]
    }
});
```

and the in the controller just pass the resolved data:

```
capValueRecruitApp.controller('offresController', function($scope, offresDetail) {
    $scope.offresDetail = offresDetail.data;
});
```

You should handle the error message in your service.

Comment: thanks now I can see the url in the navigator, but how can I read that parameter I passed since the code I wrote didn't work

Comment: I'm afraid to say that it didn't work please see the modification I made for further informations

Comment: Can you test that API method? Is it working correctly? If that resource does not exist it will probably return 404 (depending on your api) and so you will not get access to your route.

Comment: Yes I have test it and it works, when I dont use the resolve in app.js the 'views/offres.html' is injected instead of 'views/offres.detail.html'